# Coordinates of MeshPoints

Tags: plotting, evaluation

The output of a set of differential equations solved with `NDSolve` produces a series of curves and I need to obtain the spacing between these curves at a given level on the y axis. I use `MeshFunctions` and `Mesh` to produce points on
the plot.
I need to find out the {t,y} values of these points.

The nb is as follows:

```
eqns = {Table[y[i]'[t] == 15 - (Exp[i]*10*Exp[-2*t] + 3)*y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}],
  Table[y[i][0] == 5, {i, 0, 3}]};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, Table[y[i], {i, 0, 3}], {t, 10}];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}] /. sol], {t, 0, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 - 3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}];
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the two solutions for each `i`:

```
r = {};
eqns = {Table[y[i]'[t] == 15 - (Exp[i]*10*Exp[-2*t] + 3)*y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}], 
        Table[With[{ii = i}, {y[i][0] == 5, 
                             WhenEvent[y[ii][t] == 3, AppendTo[r, {ii, t}]]}], 
                                                                   {i, 0, 3}]};
sol = NDSolve[eqns, Table[y[i], {i, 0, 3}], {t, 10}];
r

(*
  {{0, 0.0605192},  {0, 1.00734}, 
   {1, 0.019865},   {1, 1.5086}, 
   {2, 0.00705075}, {2, 2.0086}, 
   {3, 0.00256151}, {3, 2.5086}}
*)

LogLogPlot[
 Evaluate[Table[y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}] /. sol], {t, 0.000001, 6}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#2 - 3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Idially, I would prefer only the points after the minimae. (i took latin a large number of years ago.)

Answer (score 0):

```
Flatten[Table[NSolve[(y[i][t] /. sol) == 3, t], {i, 0, 3}], 2]
```

(*
{t -> 1.00734, t -> 1.5086, t -> 2.0086, t -> 668.12}
*)

Comment: Three first points are OK but last one is wrong (668,12).

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure? Try `eqns = {Table[
    y[i]'[t] == 15 - (Exp[i]*10*Exp[-2*t] + 3)*y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}], 
   Table[y[i][0] == 5, {i, 0, 3}]};sol = NDSolve[eqns, Table[y[i], {i, 0, 3}], {t, 0, 700}];Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[i][t], {i, 0, 3}] /. sol], {t, 0, 700}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 6}]`

Comment: Ah.. the solution from the range `{0, 10}` in the problem does not extrapolate accurately to large $t$.  Indeed if you force the solution range to be large, you get a (slightly) different solution.  Fair enough.